# Deleting Cell value the cell in the next column is the same

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to have a VBA clean up and format data every time a table is refreshed. There are two columns that I want to look at. one is Job #, and the next one is Top level Job #. I would like the vba to look at column E, and if E5 = D5, then delete the contents in E5. If they are not the same, keep the content in E5. I would like it to do that for however many rows in Column E there are, as this will constantly change. If more information is needed let me know.

Comment: Do you want it to look at D6 = E6 etc? or only D5 = E5 and then delete the whole column?

Comment: I want to it look at all the rest of the cells in those columns that have something in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("D1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End With

    Set rng = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    MsgBox rng.Address

        For Each cell In rng
            If LCase(cell.Value) = LCase(cell.Offset(0, -1)) Then

                cell.ClearContents

            End If
        Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to remove the pop up message do I just delete "MsgBox rng.Address" ?

Comment: Yes just do that :-)